# Connect to AWS ElastiCache with In-Transit Encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, redis, amazon-elasticache

ElastiCache with encryption uses TLS to communicate with redis client, yet as I've seen redis clients in all languages (ioredis, predis, go-redis) require a pem file when configuring the client to us TLS.

How can I connect to Elasticache with in-transit encryption without given the ceritificate for the TLS?

Comment: I don't know anything about elasticache or redis, but somehow the client has to authenticate itself or anybody could connect to your elasticache instance.

Comment: It's limited with a security group with specific vpc subnets

Comment: I too am having this issue. The documentation doesn't mention anything about a certificate for in-transit encryption... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/in-transit-encryption.html

Comment: The answer is provided in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51660056/connect-to-aws-elasticache-with-in-transit-encryption-auth-from-client-other-t

Comment: @JoseMiguelColella its the same answer and I answered it in February

Answer (score 10, accepted):

solution - no certificate is needed, just to enable TLS in the client (ioredis for example is just to have `tls: {}`

Comment: Is this answer still valid for AWS ElasticCache with in-transit encryption enabled? I'm trying to connect to my cluster via a Ruby or NodeJS client (both ioredis and redis packages) and am constantly getting ECONNRESETs from the server. When I use stunnel with redis-cli everything connects and works fine though...

Comment: I used in-transit and in-rest. both worked. ioredis with blank tls worked out of the box. I also asked amazon support and thats what they said

Comment: @NickGinanto If we set the tls: {}, is the traffic in transit still encrypted?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working demo code using Predis.

```
$servers = ['tls://master.my-test-redis.8juowe.euw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379']; // your endpoint
$options = ['parameters' => ['password' =>   $password ]]; // put your password here
$redis   = new Predis\Client($servers, $options ); // Instance your client
```

Comment: I have a doubt how can we connect using enpoint alone , Do we need to specify the secret and key to access aws