# Connect to AWS ElastiCache with In-Transit Encryption + Auth from client other than redis-cli+stunnel

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to use a [Ruby](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) redis client and either one of two NodeJS clients ([node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) or [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis)) to connect to an Amazon ElastiCache cluster with in-transit encryption and auth enabled and am having issues. For all three clients, as soon as I connect I get an ECONNRESET error thrown immediately and over and over again when connection retries occur.

I have followed the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/in-transit-encryption.html) and am able to successfully connect via redis-cli using stunnel, but haven't been able to connect with any other client so far.

From looking at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635016/connect-to-aws-elasticache-with-in-transit-encryption), it appears there is no certificate required and we simply need to pass empty options to the TLS config (if applicable), but no matter what I enter I'm unsuccessful. I've also tried passing the default stunnel `stunnel.pem` private key as the cert in all clients just in case, and it obviously doesn't work either. Any assistance or expertise from others who have used ElastiCache would be helpful!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For both clients the default TLS behavior is to verify the server certificate, which we needed to disable. The solution for both clients is as follows:

NodeJS client:

```
const redis = require('redis')
const client = redis.createClient({host: hostOrIp, port: 6379, auth_pass: 'thePassword', tls: { checkServerIdentity: () => undefined }})
```

Ruby client:

```
require "redis"
redis = Redis.new(url: connectionString, ssl_params: { verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE })
```

Comment: THANK YOU. From my node client I was getting `Error: Redis connection to <host>:6379 failed - read ECONNRESET` and could not figure this out. I was trying with only the `auth_pass` param in the client connection and adding the `tls` param did the trick

Comment: Many thanks to Lance Whatley. You save my day. Hope this post can resolve the problem for who has trouble with connecting AWS Elasticache Redis with Node.js. Btw, thePassword in the code should be quoted like 'thePassword'

Comment: Thanks @FrankLiu I just fixed it in the answer.

Comment: `password` is the documented param but `auth_pass` works. Thanks for this answer!!

Comment: @ricka `auth_pass` is documented as an alias

Comment: For Googlers, this is no longer needed, Elasticache Redis certificates now have correct hostnames set.

Comment: @dz902 - Did you need to download the certs for Elasticache Redis in this case or provide it in the code. If so, how did you provide it?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar problem, but instead of ECONNRESET I was getting a timeout. For me, there were a few problems that had to be ironed out

- The lambda needs [VPC permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-ec.html#vpc-ec-create-iam-role).
- The ElastiCache security group needs an inbound rule from the Lambda security group that allows communication on the Redis port. I thought they could just be in the same security group.
- Because encryption in-transit was turned on, I needed to pass `redis.RedisClient(... ssl=True)`. The [redis-py](https://pypi.org/project/redis/) page mentions that `ssl_cert_reqs` needs to be set to `None` for use with ElastiCache similar to what was answered, but that didn't seem to be true in my case. I think AWS has updated the ElastiCache certs to have the proper hostname. I did however need to pass `ssl=True`.

It makes sense that `ssl=True` needed to be set but the connection was just timing out so I went round and round trying to figure out what the problem with the permissions/VPC/SG setup was.

Comment: Good to know that you didn't have to disable cert validation.  TLS without cert validation isn't secure against MITM attacks.

Comment: Did you need to download the certs for Elasticache Redis in this case or provide it in the code. If so, how did you provide it?

Comment: I did not need to download any certs.

Comment: where was this ssl=True set? I do not see the option using ioredis.

Comment: I was using redis-py not ioredis so I passed it into `RedisClient()`. This is probably what you're looking for: https://github.com/luin/ioredis#tls-options.