# How to connect to MemoryStore Redis server from Laravel app in GAE Flex

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I'm using GAE Flex environment to serve a Laravel application. I have setup everything and the app is working. I have also setup MemoryStore Redis server and tried to connect to the server from GAE Flex Laravel app but when I try to deploy my app I get `Predis\Connection\ConnectionException: Connection timed out [tcp://10.70.**.**:6379]` error.

I have setup MemoryStore Redis server and get the IP address of the server and put it into my app.yaml file as follows. My app is in the `us-east1` region and MemoryStore Redis region is also `us-east1`.

I also followed Google's official documentation: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex

This is working for a pure PHP app but not working for Laravel app. It is not required but I also created a VPC and tried with it too but it did not work neither.

I also asked it to Google Cloud Support but they could not help neither and since it is Laravel related they suggested me to ask it to the Stackoverflow community.

```
runtime: php
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

runtime_config:
  document_root: public
  front_controller_file: index.php
  whitelist_functions: proc_open
  enable_stackdriver_integration: true

env_variables:
  MYSQL_USER: dbusername
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: ******
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:dbname=mydbname;unix_socket=/cloudsql/project-name:us-east1:sql-server-name

  APP_URL: https://www.myapp.com
  APP_KEY: ******

  APP_ENV: local
  APP_DEBUG: true
  APP_LOG: stackdriver
  APP_LOG_LEVEL: debug
  LOG_CHANNEL: stackdriver

  DB_CONNECTION: mysql
  DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1
  DB_PORT: 3306
  DB_DATABASE: mydbname
  DB_USERNAME: dbusername
  DB_PASSWORD: ******
  DB_SOCKET: /cloudsql/project-name:us-east1:sql-server-name

  BROADCAST_DRIVER: log
  CACHE_DRIVER: redis
  QUEUE_CONNECTION: database
  SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
  SESSION_LIFETIME: 120

  REDIS_HOST: "10.70.**.**"
  REDIS_PORT: "6379"

  FILESYSTEM_DRIVER: local

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: project-name:us-east1:sql-server-name

network:
  name: default
```

I expect to connect to the MemoryStore Redis without any errors. But I still get this error:

```
Step #2:    Predis\Connection\ConnectionException  : Connection timed out [tcp://10.70.**.**:6379]
Step #2:
Step #2:   at /app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:155
Step #2:     151|      */
Step #2:     152|     protected function onConnectionError($message, $code = null)
Step #2:     153|     {
Step #2:     154|         CommunicationException::handle(
Step #2:   > 155|             new ConnectionException($this, static::createExceptionMessage($message), $code)
Step #2:     156|         );
Step #2:     157|     }
Step #2:     158|
Step #2:     159|     /**
Step #2:
Step #2:   Exception trace:
Step #2:
Step #2:   1   Predis\Connection\AbstractConnection::onConnectionError("Connection timed out")
Step #2:       /app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php:128
Step #2:
Step #2:   2   Predis\Connection\StreamConnection::createStreamSocket(Object(Predis\Connection\Parameters), "tcp://10.70.**.**:6379")
Step #2:       /app/vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/StreamConnection.php:178
```

Comment: Same error here, did you fix it?

Comment: No, I still cannot use Redis with GAE Flex. Even Google support team could not help me.

Comment: I eventually tried to start a redis store in `europe-west1` rather than `europe-west4` it doesn't make anysense but it worked.

Comment: Are you running Cloud SQL in `europe-west1` and MemoryStore Redis server in `europe-west4`?

Comment: no europe-west4 for cloud sql

Comment: Do you run a Laravel application on GAE Flex? and are you now able to use Redis with it?

Comment: I am able to connect to the Redis MemoryStore from GAE flex without the connection timeout issue you are describing. Lavarel is irrelevant here. You can try `redis-cli` you will get the same issue. It is a networking issue.

Comment: It doesn't work with Laravel but it works fine with [GAE Flex NodeJS example](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-flex#nodejs_2).

Comment: Do you have a way to log what is the connection Lavarel is trying to make?

Comment: You can find the "Connection timed out" error log in my question. What else do you need?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635016/connect-to-aws-elasticache-with-in-transit-encryption/51193017#51193017 ?

Comment: `tls://` rather than `tcp://`

Comment: Yes I've tried TLS connection and got same timeout error `Step #1:    Predis\Connection\ConnectionException
Step #1:
Step #1:   Connection timed out [tls://10.231.**.**:6379]
Step #1:
Step #1:   at vendor/predis/predis/src/Connection/AbstractConnection.php:155
Step #1:     151|      */
Step #1:     152|     protected function onConnectionError($message, $code = null)
Step #1:     153|     {
Step #1:     154|         CommunicationException::handle(
Step #1:   > 155|             new ConnectionException($this, static::createExceptionMessage($message), $code)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution to this issue. There were two commands to prepare caches before using the app. I've removed these commands from `post-install-cmd` in the `composer.json` file. If anyone needs more detail I can help them. Just comment here.

Before:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
    "chmod -R 777 bootstrap\/cache",
    "chmod -R 777 storage",
    "php artisan cache:clear",
    "php artisan optimize"
]
```

After:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
    "chmod -R 777 bootstrap\/cache",
    "chmod -R 777 storage",
]
```